# CrafterCMS: Crafter Engine doesn't seem to notice changes in the /classes/groovy folder

Tags: java, groovy, content-management-system

Crafter Engine doesn’t seem to notice files changed in the `/classes/groovy` folder. When we modify a groovy file there, it takes a Tomcat restart for it to be used. Is this a known issue or by design?

```
/opt/crafter/master>grep -r /classes/groovy engine/
engine/src/main/resources/crafter/engine/services/main-services-context.xml:        <property name="groovyClassesPath" value="/classes/groovy"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Groovy classes become part of the classloader, so normally changes on them are not picked up. The best way for the changes to be apply is to rebuild the site's context, which will delete the old classloader. To rebuild call the API `/api/1/site/context/rebuild.json`. The deployer can be configured also to call this API any time files under /classes/groovy are changed.